# vBulletin merging old database and new database

Tags: merge, backup, vbulletin

How to merge old database with new database?

I need to add all stuff (topics, comments, users and all info) from one db to other...

vBulletin 3.7.3 (both dbs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImpEx. https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/impex/